# Conditional code for changing colors with html text, with shiny inputs prints code rather than apply it

Tags: shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity, flexdashboard

I'm working on a dashboard built with flexdashboard and Shiny, (and other libraries but they're irrelevant for this example. My goal is to have bare text code change color according to the values the variables get (from the inputs, of course). I've been trying to replicate what I found in the following post: https://community.rstudio.com/t/variable-colour-with-the-if-condition/78015/2

However, my code has the difference that I'm using shiny inputs, so, the parameter I pass onto "var" is reactive. I haven't found the right way to send the code as bare text rather than as a "renderText" chunk.

My code is:

````
```{r}
color_if <- function(var) {
color <- if (var > 1) "green" else "red"
sprintf("<span style='color: %s;'>%s</span>", color, var)
}

```


Row{data-height=220}
----

<p style="font: bebas; font-size:13pt; font-style:normal;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;">
<b> % Var </b>
</p>

`r renderText(color_if(var_comparativa2_selected_182()))`
````

Currently this is printing as the following image:

[image]

How can I have it "apply" the code rather than rendering it? I've previously tried renderUI, renderText, even reactive, without success. If there is any different approach, I'd really appreciate the comments.

Also, this is a very small part of my dashboard which has already over 2k+ lines of code, so changing it completely to, for example ShinyDashboard, would be a little difficult for me.

Comment: Try to put the code in the `HTML` function and use `renderUI` instead of `renderText`.

Comment: So, I'm now trying 

``r renderUI(ifelse(var_comparativa2_selected_182() > 0, "<span style='color:green;'>var_comparativa2_selected_182()</span>", "<span style='color:red;'>var_comparativa2_selected_182()</span>"))``

Still with a similar result, it'll print the html code directly on the rmarkdown canvas

Comment: `HTML("<span ......)`

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneLaurent your comments, along with some tweking, helped me figure it out, I'm sharing a full answer.